# How to implement client-side authentication (2 way SSL) in QWC-compatible web service?

Tags: web, desktop, quickbooks, connector

I have created web connector compatible service and deployed it to cloud. For security, I am planning to do 2-way SSL that includes client authentication i.e. the web connector will provide the certificate and the service will authenticate the client i.e. the web connector. I am planning to host these certificates in a truststore which the web service will use. But, I couldn't find anything in the web connector documentation about how/where I can specify the path for client certificate/key or truststore on web connector side? How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Web Connector doesn't support what you're describing, so you won't be able to do this with the Web Connector.

The Web Connector does this for security:

- requires all connections to be over SSL/TLS (https) so that data in transit is encrypted
- authenticates with a username and a password

You can further secure this by following standard web app security things like:

- rate limiting how quickly people can auth
- blocking IPs or usernames that fail auth too many times
- configuring your web server to only use TLS v1.2 (no SSLv2, SSLv2, or old TLS)
- enforce secure passwords
- store the passwords on your end hashed
- etc.